# Trustpilot Widget not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-chat, trustpilot

**when I add trust pilot widget to the Site**

```
            <div
              className="trustpilot-widget"
              data-locale="en-GB"
              data-template-id="54****************9ad"
              data-businessunit-id="6*****************de"
              data-style-height="24px"
              data-style-width="100%"
              data-theme="light"
              data-min-review-count="10"
            >
              <a
                href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/*******.**"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                Trustpilot
              </a>
            </div>
```

[image]

**Trust Pilot widget is not loading sometimes, when the facebook API request is failed I think**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are not using any adblockers, and also make sure your browser accepts third-party cookies as well. Could you please explain the screenshots? Are these from your own website or just a website?

Comment: for sure I'm not using add blockers, even though it's same & this is my own website

Comment: I'm having problem with trustpilot widget not showing on some newer designs that they offer like the "Slider" with different plugins, like it's not being support

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the trustpilot script in the head of your page, that is what actually loads the iframe.
It should be something like this:

```
<Script  src="https://widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).